# Why am I being captured in Age of Conquest 4?

Tags: age-of-conquest-4

I recently downloaded Age of Conquest 4, I got a hang of stuff quite quickly and I really enjoy playing it with friends, but it really annoys me when I am in the process of invading a country and then all of a sudden my leader gets captured and I'm back to square one again, so can someone please tell me why my leader is being captured?? and how do I prevent this??

Answer (score 1):

Your leader (aka "commander") is shown on the map as a little crown over one of the armies. When moving that army, there is a checkbox you can tick to move the commander. I have no idea what effect the leader has on battles, so I just move him into the center of my territory and leave him there.